# Composer library can't find dependency

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php, autoload, packagist

I made my first php library available through packagist. I'm still figuring out how it works, but I keep getting this exception:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Waspeer\NextAction\FabianBeiner\Todoist\TodoistClient' not found in /home/deb58323n2/domains/wannessalome.nl/public_html/assets/todoist/vendor/waspeer/todoist-next-action/src/NextAction.php:120
```

I listed `FabianBeiner\Todoist` as a dependency in my composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.1.0",
    "fabian-beiner/todoist-php-api-library": "^0.7.2"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Waspeer\\NextAction\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

And this is in my library file:

```
namespace Waspeer\NextAction;

use FabianBeiner\Todoist\TodoistClient;
```

It seems like it's trying to find the dependency in the folder of my library, but I don't know why and how to solve this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! When I changed `new FabianBein\Todoist\TodoistClient` later in the code to just `new TodoistClient` it worked. Guess I don't really get yet how this `use` statement/autoloading works..